# cancan for new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I added new action to my restful resources how can I authorize it with cancan.

Pages controller:

```
load_and_authorize_resource


 def index    
 end

 def show
 end

 def new
 end

 def create
 end

 def edit
 end

 def update
 end

 def destroy
 end 

 def mynewaction
 end
```

Ability model:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
      user ||= User.new
      can :create, Page
      can :mynewmethod, Page #does it work?

  end
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Also you can put the methods togheter passing by array like 

can [:create, :mynewmethod], Page

Answer (score 4):

Yes I believe it works for things other than the CRUD methods, although this is just from looking at some of the documentation, check out [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorizing-Controller-Actions) and the [actual documentation by ryanb here](http://rdoc.info/github/ryanb/cancan/master/CanCan/Ability).

You should especially look at that first link that says that the `load_and_authorize_resource` will apply to all methods in the controller, even ones other than the usual CRUD  ones.

I think the easiest way is just to test it out, does it authorize correctly when you fire it up? Nothing better than to try.

Comment: Paul is correct both on the standpoint of it working as outlined and throwing a test out there to confirm.